# moving multiple files

Tags: grep, mv

i have a downloadsfolder that contains 9 items backup.sh ,bestanden.sh, tara.tar.gz, nmap.tar.bz2, demo11.zip, contract.pdf, cleaning.pdf, GNU-linux.jpg and video.mp4.
these have to get sorted in the documentsfolder where there are 2 deviding folders.
one is called 'werk' the other is named 'thuis'.

'werk' contains 3 folders Scripts, backup and contract
backup.sh ,bestanden.sh                 should go in Scripts
tara.tar.gz, nmap.tar.bz2, demo11.zip   should go in backup
contract.pdf, cleaning.pdf              should go in contract

'thuis' contains one file called foto
GNU-linux.jpg and video.mp4             should go in the foto folder.

The problem is not that i cant move them, the problem is i am looking for just one command to do all of these moves in one go.

Comment: You may want to start here. In a terminal type man mv